# Using /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu instead of /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu to find_library in CMake

Tags: c++, linux, cmake, i386

How can I make CMake look for i386 libraries instead of x86_64 ones?

I'm trying to build i386 linux executables on machine for later deployment. I've made sure I've installed the i386 version of my dependencies, and they under `/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu`, while the 64bit libraries are under `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu`, as expected.

However, I can't seem to find a way to make CMake look under `/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu` for my libraries when building 32 bit. Setting make `CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS` to include `-m32` only causes linking to fail, since the compiler is building a 32 bit executable and trying to link 64bit libraries to it, which it obviously can't do. It does this because it somehow prefers to get `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libsfml-system.so` over `/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libsfml-system.so` for example.

---

**What I've tried so far:**

- Adding `-m32` to my compile flags, caused executable not to link
- Setting my `CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH` to `/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu`, hoping it would look under that directory first, though it still found the 64 bit versions of the libraries.

---

I don't really have any more ideas, although I'm actively researching on forums, but I can't seem to find much that is useful. Maybe someone here has an idea of  what I could do next.

---

**My CMakeLists.txt as of now:**

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.5)
project(Synapse)

set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -std=c++17 -pthread -O3 -m32")

set(CMAKE_SYSTEM_PROCESSOR i386)
set(CMAKE_SYSTEM_NAME Linux)
set(CMAKE_SYSTEM_VERSION gnu)

set(CMAKE_MODULE_PATH ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/cmake_modules)

find_package(SFML 2.4 COMPONENTS system window graphics network audio REQUIRED)
include_directories(${SFML_INCLUDE_DIR})

message(STATUS ${SFML_LIBRARIES})

set(CLIENT_SOURCE_FILES Client/main.cpp types.h Client/Mouse.cpp Client/Mouse.h Client/Game.cpp Client/Game.h Client/Camera.cpp Client/Camera.h Client/Renderer.cpp Client/Renderer.h Networking.h)
add_executable(SynapseClient ${CLIENT_SOURCE_FILES})

set(SERVER_SOURCE_FILES Server/main.cpp types.h Server/Game.cpp Server/Game.h Server/Commander.cpp Server/Commander.h Server/Unit.cpp Server/Unit.h Server/Client.cpp Server/Client.h Networking.h Server/Log.cpp Server/Log.h Server/User.cpp Server/User.h)
add_executable(SynapseServer ${SERVER_SOURCE_FILES})

target_link_libraries(SynapseClient ${SFML_LIBRARIES})
target_link_libraries(SynapseServer ${SFML_LIBRARIES})
```

Comment: What's in `${SFML_INCLUDE_DIR} ?`

Comment: @fedepad `/usr/include`, as expected.

Comment: so it looks like you have the "system" sfml, you didn't install from source in a custom location.

Comment: @fedepad Yes, I have installed both 32bit SFML libraries and 64bit SFML libraries from the package manager.

Comment: could you try to put `set(SFML_ROOT "/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu")` right before `find_package(SFML 2.4 COMPONENTS system window graphics network audio REQUIRED)` ?

Comment: @fedepad no bingo

Comment: not even if you pass SFML_ROOT in the command line instead of setting it inside the CMakeLists.txt? And another point: you should not only modify the compile flags, but also the link flags for 32 bits...

Comment: @fedepad granted, but if CMake isn't finding the 32bit libraries for me, nothing is gonna work from there. Passing from command line and setting inside the file should have the same effect.

Comment: I agree, it should be the same, I just wanted to see if cmake itself had some weird behavior for that, although unlikely, but never know.

Comment: It turns out CLion is doing some weird shit. It seems to be providing another `CMAKE_LIBRARY_ARCHITECTURE`. If I run from console I have the expected output. Very interesting.

Comment: Ok, I didn't know you are using it from within Clion...I assumed from the console.

Comment: @fedepad Now it's even worse. Console always gives me i386 and CLion always gives me x86_64.

Comment: @fedepad Ok, it was a cache problem. Clearing the cache makes everything roll.

Comment: Ok, good to know!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let CMake know that you do not want to search the 64bit paths before calling 
`find_package()`:

```
set_property(GLOBAL PROPERTY FIND_LIBRARY_USE_LIB64_PATHS OFF)
```

Documentation:

- [FIND_LIBRARY_USE_LIB64_PATHS](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/prop_gbl/FIND_LIBRARY_USE_LIB64_PATHS.html)
- [FIND_LIBRARY_USE_LIB32_PATHS](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/prop_gbl/FIND_LIBRARY_USE_LIB32_PATHS.html)